# Any queries to the api.linkedin.com/v2/ return "Not enough permissions to access ..."

Tags: linkedin-api

1. I got the *Access Token* (with scope: `r_basicprofile rw_company_admin w_share`) using the *Client ID*, *Client Secret* at following URLs:

   - https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
   - https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
2. Make request to the https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me endpoint

   ```
   curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
       -H "Accept: application/json"
       -H "Content-Type: application/json"
       -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
   ```
3. Get response:

   ```
   {
       "serviceErrorCode": 100,
       "message": "Not enough permissions to access /me GET ",
       "status": 403
   }
   ```

Similar erroneous responses are returned to any requests for https://api.linkedin.com/v2/

In official documentation there is difference requirements to headers:

- [`X-Rest**l**i-Protocol-Version`](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/protocol-version)
- [`X-Rest**L**i-Protocol-Version`](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api)

But I tried both, and nothing worked.

Requests to the https://api.linkedin.com/v1/ (using the same token) successfully return data.

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: this may help you - https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this API-client doesn't solve my problem (I successfully authorized by /v2/ endpoint). The problem is that any requests for /v2/ to receive data (excluding authorization requests) are returned with an error.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this - I am experiencing the same error.

Comment: Sorry. No news yet.

Comment: Hi, I also made some tests and same error (403). Should we need to ask Linkedin to authorize API V2 for our application?

Comment: I am having the same problem. OAuth completes fine, every and any v2 calls return the error below. I am beginning to think that the LinkedIn API v2 broken... Anyone figured this out?

`{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access /me GET ",
    "status": 403
}`

Comment: @gabics If you already have an application using the v1 API, you can try to use `r_liteprofile` instead of `r_basicprofile` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context, especially where it says `r_liteprofile (replaces r_basicprofile)`).

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**You need to request permissions from LinkedIn.**

**Now all requests to api.linkedin.com/v2/ successfully pass to me!**

We received permissions (**r_ad_campaigns** and **rw_organization**) after request offer by address https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Leave a request at the address below and LinkedIn will answer you.

Good luck!

Comment: We are already partners and having the permissions : r_basicprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress
r_fullprofile r_network rw_company_admin
rw_groups rw_nus w_messages
w_share Is this enough to call v2 api? I'm having the exact 403 issue above.

Comment: Permission `r_ad_campaigns` and `rw_organization` is required to access `/v2/me`?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api#usage), rights r_ad_campaigns and rw_organization are not required to access /v2/me. But maybe it's worth writing to technical support of LinkedIn.

Comment: @Pavel Timofeev, I am facing same sort of issue. Please let me know if its resolved after getting permissions r_ad_campaigns and rw_organization

Comment: @javadev did you solve the issue? do we have to once again apply for the "marketing developer program"?

Comment: @DeviOS Now you will only have access to r_liteprofile permissions by default. That is sufficient to have the v2/me response. But for maintining the basic profile and full profile fields you will need more permissions from linkedin, ony available upon Linkedin approval.

Comment: @javadev my application is an old one, we have already got approval earlier like some years back. so do we need to get approval again from linkedin?

Comment: @DeviOS According to this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq, you do.

Comment: I have been approved in the developer program, I have the rw_company_admin permission. When I do my research, they say I need  r_organization_social or rw_organization but I get unauthorized_scope_error. Is there a setting I need to change on my app?

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande Do you have "rw_organization_admin", "r_organization_social" and "r_member_social" permissions at your App's settings page? https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/auth If not, you need to apply for the "marketing developer program"

Answer (score 17):

Use `r_liteprofile` instead of `r_basicprofile` during the first step of `Authorization`.
This will solve your issue.

Comment: @Vijay in `v2` you need permission for `r_basicprofile`

Answer (score 6):

API access changed and what you received with only 1 API call, now has to be rewritten to make multiple API calls

Before, using scope "r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress" you could get

- User basic info as name, location etc
- LinkedIn user profile URL
- Email
- Avatar image

Now you can use "r_basicprofile" that will get you user LinkedIn public URL only if you are in a [partner program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context), and it is not easy to get in!

**If you want to get `access_token` which you can use to get basic profile info + email, now you have to request it with a scope "r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress"**

and use this 3 API calls to get all the details, unfortunately without Linkedin public URL (if anyone knows how to get this, please comment so I can modify the answer)

1. profile info - `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`
2. email - `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))`
3. profile image - `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))`
4. public profile URL - not possible!

#### Acess token

Use this link for retrival description

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: I want to get the r_basicprofile and tried it many ways but not getting the correct solution yet! have you got any solution?

Comment: In their official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext#public-profile-url) today, they say you can get profile url via `vanityName` from basic profile result ie `GET /v2/userinfo`