# LinkedIn API v2 endpoints do not work

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn has two API versions, v1 and v2. Recently, I was told that LinkedIn does not guarantee their v1-API will work and that we should have migrated to v2 years ago, this information was shared with us by a LinkedIn support employee. As a result of this info, I'm trying to migrate an application to v2.

Our customers can provide us with an OAuth2-token which has administrative rights for a company page. With that token, we will retrieve posts and comments from that company page. If I use the v1-API, it works without any issues, but I can't make a successful request with the v2-API. I've tried to use the following endpoint: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sharesPerOwner=100. There are several things I've tried.

- Putting the token in an Authorization header, which works for v1 (Authorization: Bearer ).
- Putting the token in the query params (https://api.linkedin.com/v2/...?oauth2_access_token=&...).
- Using the numeric id of a company page, rather than the full  urn:li:organization:.
- Putting the id in parentheses.
- Using the newest version of the protocol by setting the following header: "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0".

If I use the newest version of the protocol, I always get Bad Request Errors (code 400), otherwise I get a Forbidden Error (code 403). I've also tried to retrieve the Organization Access Control Information using the following endpoint, https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee, but the same issue persists. This is strange to me, because as far as I know I do have sufficient rights to retrieve that data.

I've checked LinkedIn's developer documentation multiple times by myself and with colleagues, unfortunately the quality is rather abysmal. Is this API even supposed to work? Am I missing some undocumented permissions? 
Have I made a mistake in one of my parameters? Do we need to use OAuth in a different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this too.  They make you ask for V2 permissions and fill out a form with a bunch of required fields.  It takes up to 30 days for approval.  The link is in this post .

[Any queries to the api.linkedin.com/v2/ return "Not enough permissions to access ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960458/any-queries-to-the-api-linkedin-com-v2-return-not-enough-permissions-to-access)

Comment: So if we are already a partner where is the form to fill out in order to have access to v2 api? Please help.

Comment: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program#submit

Comment: @jasonw I've done my request for the "Marketing Developer Platform" about 2 months ago, and its review is still in progress... How long it takes to you?